# Xcode 5 - No Crash or no console logs

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, ios7.1

Team,

I got a crash when I perform below actions in my simulator,

```
>     Navigated to Screen1 - > Screen2- > Screen3 -> Screen2 -> screen1
>     Press home screen - Go to iPhone Settings screen -> Relaunch my application
>     then perform the same steps (Screen1 - > Screen2- > Screen3 -> Screen2 -> screen1)
>     perform the same steps Screen1 -> screen2 -> Screen3 -> CRASH on [super viewDidLoad]
```

I don't see any crash logs or console logs for the crash, but my debugger stops at this point.

[image]

[image]

Any idea why my application crashes only when I minimized and relaunch the application. If I don't minimize the application, everything works as expected.

Why I am not able to view any console logs for the crash?

Note: We tested on iOS6 device and there is no crash, this is observed only in iOS7 device. I can reproduce the crash only when I minimize the application, else it works fine.

seen this log only once,

```
2014-04-16 11:42:05.073 ADTCommercial[36614:60b] -[CALayerArray leading]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xac1a690
2014-04-16 11:42:05:077 ADTCommercial[36614:60b] 
*÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷*
    * An Exception Has Been Handled! *

Method:
    -[ADT_TaskHomeList(Custom) tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] -
Exception Name:
    NSInvalidArgumentException
Exception Reason:
    -[CALayerArray leading]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xac1a690
StackTrace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x031af1e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x03d7e8e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0324c243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0319f50b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0319f0ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   ADTCommercial                       0x005aa1d1 +[AMPListScreenTableViewCell getHeightForFont:numberOfLines:] + 113
    6   ADTCommercial                       0x0059dd80 -[AMPGeneratedListViewController invalidate] + 224
    7   ADTCommercial                       0x0059e4f8 -[AMPGeneratedListViewController setNumberOfLines:] + 360
    8   ADTCommercial                       0x0059d28e -[AMPGeneratedListViewController viewDidLoad] + 270
    9   ADTCommercial                       0x00107208 -[ADT_SystemDetails(Custom) viewDidLoad] + 72
    10  UIKit                               0x02122e10 -[UIViewController awakeFromNib] + 110
    11  UIKit                               0x022bbf67 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1955
    12  UIKit                               0x022bdada -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 165
    13  ADTCommercial                       0x005c1f7b -[AMPViewManager loadView] + 811
    14  ADTCommercial                       0x005b6916 -[AMPScreenManager showScreen:withRow:createScreen:reloadPolicy:doReset:isModal:animated:navigationController:] + 3542
    15  ADTCommercial                       0x0058b1ec +[AMPStandardActions gotoAction:reloadPolicy:transactionStateChange:addToHistory:] + 252
    16  ADTCommercial                       0x002c4935 -[ADT_TaskHomeList(Custom) tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 901
    17  UIKit                               0x020f09a1 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1513
    18  UIKit                               0x020f0b14 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 279
    19  UIKit                               0x020f510e __38-[UITableView touchesEnded:withEvent:]_block_invoke + 43
    20  UIKit                               0x020240aa ___afterCACommitHandler_block_invoke + 15
    21  UIKit                               0x02024055 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 403
    22  UIKit                               0x02023e76 _afterCACommitHandler + 532
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0317736e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x031772bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x03155254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x031549d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x031547eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x04e805ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    29  GraphicsServices                    0x04e8042b GSEventRun + 104
    30  UIKit                               0x02006f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    31  ADTCommercial                       0x0000642e main + 126
    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x044c4701 start + 1
    33  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
*÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷÷*
```

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

```
PMPCAccountInfoTabScreen *accountsInfoTabScreen = nil;
PMPCJobWrapUp *wrapUpScreen = nil;

NSString *screenPushedUnderJobWrapUp = @"SCREEN_PUSHED_UNDER_WRAP_UP";
@try {
    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case 0:
            // PUSH THE ACCOUNT INFORMATION SCREEN
            accountsInfoTabScreen = (PMPCAccountInfoTabScreen*)[[[PMPCScreenManager sharedScreenManager] getScreen:@"PMPCAccountInfoTabScreen"] view];
            [accountsInfoTabScreen setSelectedTab:0];
            [PMPCStandardActions gotoAction:@"PMPCAccountInfoTabScreen" reloadPolicy:PMPCScreenReloadAlways transactionStateChange:PMPCTransactionContinue addToHistory:YES];
            [Commons setClipboardValueForKey:screenPushedUnderJobWrapUp value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
            break;

        case 1:
            // PUSH THE JOB DETAILS SCREEN
            [PMPCStandardActions gotoAction:@"JobDetailsScreen" reloadPolicy:PMPCScreenReloadAlways transactionStateChange:PMPCTransactionContinue addToHistory:YES];
            [Commons setClipboardValueForKey:screenPushedUnderJobWrapUp value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
            break;

        case 2:
            //[[PMPCDataClipboard sharedClipboard] setValueForKey:screenPushedUnderJobWrapUp value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
            [[PMPCDataClipboard sharedClipboard] removeValueForKey:screenPushedUnderJobWrapUp];
            [Commons setClipboardValueForKey:screenPushedUnderJobWrapUp value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
            [PMPCStandardActions gotoAction:@"PMPCSystemDetails" reloadPolicy:PMPCScreenReloadAlways transactionStateChange:PMPCTransactionContinue addToHistory:YES];
            break;

        case 3:
            // Add Items screen
            [Commons setClipboardValueForKey:screenPushedUnderJobWrapUp value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
            [PMPCStandardActions gotoAction:@"PMPCAddedItemsList" reloadPolicy:PMPCScreenReloadAlways transactionStateChange:PMPCTransactionContinue addToHistory:YES];
            break;

        case 4:
            // PUSH THE JOB WRAP UP SCREEN
            //JobWrapUpObject *wrapUp = [Commons getJobWrapUpObject];
            //[wrapUp resetValues];
            wrapUpScreen = (PMPCJobWrapUp*)[[[PMPCScreenManager sharedScreenManager] getScreen:@"PMPCJobWrapUp"] view];
            [wrapUpScreen setScrollToTop:YES];
            [Commons setClipboardValueForKey:screenPushedUnderJobWrapUp value:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
            [PMPCStandardActions gotoAction:@"PMPCJobWrapUp" reloadPolicy:PMPCScreenReloadAlways transactionStateChange:PMPCTransactionBegin addToHistory:YES];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    ExceptionLog(exception);
}
@finally {
    [PMPCLog trace:@"%s Ends",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__];
}
```

}

[image]
Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Try with NSZombies to find if an object don't exist when it should.

Comment: 2014-04-16 11:46:58.962 ADTCommercial[36645:60b] *** -[CTFont retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x12d0b0a0

Comment: I commented [super dealloc] from the dealloc method and crash vanished away. I know its not the right approach, can you please let me know any other ways to fix the crash?

Comment: Are you using ARC in your project ?

Comment: can we see your ADT_TaskHomeList , tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

Comment: @rustylepord, Any idea?